# Is Forefront Identity Manager required for user profile synchronization service in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: user-profile-service

I want to configure user profile synchronization service in SharePoint 2013 environment. Does anyone know the steps to configure the same?

Is Forefront Identity Manager required to be installed for user profile synchronization service in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 3):

The high level steps are to:

1. Provision a User Profile Service Application
2. Start the User Profile Service
3. Start the Synchronization Service
4. Create a Synchronization Connection
5. Run the import

You have to choose how you want to import user profiles, you can do a direct AD sync that will not require FIM (but is limited in many ways) or use FIM to perform and import and optional export of properties.

Either way, FIM is installed as a prereq of the SharePoint installation.

The full details of all the minutia to get the UPS running are on Spence's blog: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx the article was written for 2010 but still applies.

Comment: This is correct, but the while the AD sync is limited, it certainly meets the needs of many organizations. So certainly worth checking out before defaulting to the more difficult solution.